Proving the approximation of the Hypergeometric via the Poisson
I am attempting show that the Hypergeometric distribution can be approximated by the Poisson under a few assumptions. However, I am getting stuck near the end of the proof and I cannot figure out what I am missing.
Here is the starting set of assumptions.
The Hypergeometric distribution is:
$$P(X=x)= \frac{\binom{M}{x} \binom{N-M}{K-x}}{\binom{N}{K}}$$
and the Poisson distribution is:
$$P(X=x) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x}}{x!}$$
and my assumptions are:

$M, N, K \to \infty$
$\frac{M}{N}\to 0$
$\frac{MK}{N}\to \lambda$

We will also use the Stirling approximation of the factorial:
$$n! = \sqrt{2\pi \times n} \times \frac{n^n}{e^n}$$

Begin with the following:
$$
\begin{align}
P(X=x) & =\frac{\binom{M}{x} \binom{N-M}{K-x}}{\binom{N}{K}} \\
& = \frac
{M! \times (N-M)! \times K! \times(N-K)!}
{x! \times (M-x)! \times (N-M-K-x)! \times(K-x)! \times N!} 
\end{align}
$$
Now, replace the factorials except for $x!$ with the Stirling approximation. The $\sqrt{2\pi}$ terms cancel, and so do  the exponentials except for one $e^{-x}$, yielding the following:
$$
\begin{align}
P(X=x) & =\frac{\binom{M}{x} \binom{N-M}{K-x}}{\binom{N}{K}}
\\ & = 
\frac{e^{-x}}{x!} \times 
\frac
{
M^{M+\frac{1}{2}} 
(N-M)^{(N-M+\frac{1}{2})} 
K^{K+\frac{1}{2}} 
(N-K)^{(N-K+\frac{1}{2})}
}
{
(M-X)^{(M-X+\frac{1}{2})}
(N-M-K+x)^{(N-M-K+x+\frac{1}{2})}
(K-X)^{(K-X+\frac{1}{2})}
N^{(N+\frac{1}{2})} 
} 
\\ & = \frac{e^{-x}}{x!} \times
\frac
{
M^{M} 
(N-M)^{(N-M)} 
K^{K} 
(N-K)^{(N-K)}
}
{
(M-x)^{(M-x)}
(N-M-K+x)^{(N-M-K+x)}
(K-x)^{(K-x)}
N^{N} 
}
\end{align}
$$
Now we use the definition of the exponential and limits to clean up some terms:

$(\frac{M}{M-x})^{M} = e^{x}$
$(\frac{K}{K-x})^{K} = e^{x}$
$(\frac{N-K}{N})^{N} = e^{K}$
$\frac{1}{(M-x)^{-x}} = M^{x}$ because of  $M\to\infty$
$\frac{1}{(K-x)^{-x}} = K^{x}$ because of  $K\to\infty$
$(\frac{N-M}{N-M-(K-x)})^{(N-M)} = e^{(K-x)}$ because of  $(N-M)\to\infty$ as we know $\frac{N}{M} \to 0$

If we plug these in, we should get the following mostly reduced equation:
$$
= \frac{K^{x}M^{x}}{x!} \times \frac{(N-M-K+x)^{K-x}}{(N-K)^{K}}
$$
I know that if I can show:
$$\frac{(N-M-K+x)^{K-x}}{(N-K)^{K}} = \frac{(N-M)^{K-x}}{N^K}$$
Then I can finish the proof as:
$$\frac{(N-M)^{K-x}}{N^K} = (\frac{N-M}{N})^{K-x} \times \frac{1}{N^x}  = \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{N^x}$$
Which can then be substituted back into the equation to yield the Poisson. However, I just can't figure out that second to last step. Am I missing something obvious or did I make an error before this? Any assistance would be appreciated.

See here.
